# How can I load my own/custom CSS - Django

Tags: css, django

I'm trying to load my own customized CSS in Django but with no success. The weird thing is that the main CSS (style.css) is loading correctly.

Here is my base.html:

```
<!-- Main Style CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

<!-- My Own Style CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
```

My settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls')),
    # path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('account.urls')),
    path('', include('dma.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because you didn't specify a `MEDIA_URL`, so try this:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/css/'
    
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Comment: Actually I did: `MEDIA_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`. I don't think MEDIA is the problem for not linking to my custom CSS...

Answer (score 0):

where is located your custom css ? in which static folder ?

- in **project level** `static` folder next to `css/style.css` ? in this case it should be loaded with no problem maybe you have a typo in the file name ?
- in **app** `static` folder ?
  in this case, i guess you need to add

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
```

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS

## Update

maybe you need to re-run the command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

so the new assets can be taken in consideration the next reload.

Comment: the custom css is located next to css/style.css (same folder), in other words, it's not located in the app static folder. When I run `python manage.py collectstatic` I get and error: `whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file '&amp;quot;delete-icn.svg&amp;quot;' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage o
bject at 0x0491C910>.

The CSS file 'main.css' references a file which could not be found:
  &amp;quot;delete-icn.svg&amp;quot;
`

Comment: i guess, this is an other issue nothing to do with loading your `custom.css`, it's clearly that  `whiteNoise` fails and aborts the build because it can't find resource `delete-icn.svg` referenced in your `main.css` in expected location. i suggest you check all resources and rebuild cache.